# Find $a \in \mathbb R$ such that the following system of linear equations have solutions (four (actually three) equations in four variables)

Tags: linear-algebra

**(a) Solve the following system of linear equations**

$$\begin{aligned} x_{1}+x_{2}+3 x_{3} &=0 \\ x_{1}+6 x_{3}+x_{4} &=0 \\ x_{1}-x_{2}+5 x_{3}+x_{4} &=0 \\ 2 x_{1}+2 x_{2}+10 x_{3}+x_{4} &=0 \end{aligned}$$

*my answer*

I solved it by Gauss-Jordan elimination.

$$x=\left[\begin{array}{c}{0} \\ {0} \\ {-1 / 4} \\ {0}\end{array}\right]+\left[\begin{array}{r}{2} \\ {1} \\ {-1} \\ {4}\end{array} \right],t \in \mathbb R$$

This I have doubled checked. It is correct.
Important note: the elimination shows that the bottom two equations are equivalent. So I removed $R_4$ from the matrix.

**(b) Find $a \in \mathbb R$ such that the following system of linear equations have solutions**

\begin{aligned} x_{1}+x_{2}+3 x_{3} &=1 \\ x_{1}+6 x_{3}+x_{4} &=a \\ x_{1}-x_{2}+5 x_{3}+x_{4} &=a \\ 2 x_{1}+2 x_{2}+10 x_{3}+x_{4} &=2 a \end{aligned}

*my answer*

This one I'm not to sure about. My plan is to treat $a$ like a variable. Then I have

\begin{aligned} x_{1}+x_{2}+3 x_{3} &=1 \\ x_{1}+6 x_{3}+x_{4} - a &=0 \\ x_{1}-x_{2}+5 x_{3}+x_{4} - a &=0 \\ 2 x_{1}+2 x_{2}+10 x_{3}+x_{4} -2a &=0 \end{aligned}

If I let $x_5=a$ then I have

\begin{aligned} x_{1}+x_{2}+3 x_{3} &=1 \\ x_{1}+6 x_{3}+x_{4} - x_5 &=0 \\ x_{1}-x_{2}+5 x_{3}+x_{4} - x_5 &=0 \\ 2 x_{1}+2 x_{2}+10 x_{3}+x_{4} -2x_5 &=0 \end{aligned}

After this I will able to proceed as usual with the Gauss-Jordan Elimination.

**Q: I'm note sure whether I can treat this constant $a$ as a variable. No one has been able to solve it.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce the matrix as you normally would if a were just any real number like 2 for example.

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
  1&1&3&0&1\\
  1&0&6&1&a\\
  1&-1&5&1&a\\
  2&2&10&1&2a\\
\end{array}
\right] $$    ~  R3= -R1+R3
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
  1&1&3&0&1\\
  1&0&6&1&a\\
  0&-2&2&1&a-1\\
  2&2&10&1&2a\\
\end{array}
\right] $$
~ R4=-2R2 - R4
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
  1&1&3&0&1\\
  1&0&6&1&a\\
  0&-2&2&1&a-1\\
  0&2&-2&-1&0\\
\end{array}
\right] $$
~ R3=R4+R3
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
  1&1&3&0&1\\
  1&0&6&1&a\\
  0&0&0&0&a-1\\
  0&2&-2&-1&0\\
\end{array}
\right] $$

At this point you can stop reducing. Since you have an all zero row that equals a-1, a must equal 1.

Comment: $a$ must equal $1$. That's what I think you mean. So I replace $a$ with $1$ in your last matrix. Then I continue the reduction, and I get the same system as in problem (a). So the solution will be the same as in problem (a). Is this correct?

Comment: I think you misunderstand what the question is asking. You're just asked to find a value for a such that a solution exists. If you tried using any other value than a=1 the system would be unsolvable.

Comment: Alright, I'm on board.